# Set Default emailBody to apex:emailpublisher in HTML Format

Tags: visualforce, html, service-cloud-console

I've tried to set default value to emailBody attribute of the apex:emailpublisher component with an HTML value along with setting emailbodyformat to "HTML", but when I opened the console it renders the default value without the `<br />` elements.

The visualforce page code:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="CTRL_Case_EmailReplyAll">
<apex:emailpublisher id="myEmailPublisher"
                     entityid="{!case.id}"
                     width="100%"
                     title="Reply All"
                     expandableheader="false"
                     autocollapsebody="false"
                     showadditionalfields="false"
                     fromvisibility="selectable"
                     tovisibility="editable"
                     bccvisibility="hidden"
                     ccvisibility="hidden"
                     emailbody="<html><body>Hi,<br /><br />Your ticket has been marked as solved. You can re-open it by replying to this email.<br />Below is the full thread, for your record,<br /><br />Regards,/<br /><br /></body></html>"
                     emailbodyformat="HTML"
                     subject=""
                     showtemplates="false"
                     toaddresses="{!toAddresses}"
                     onsubmitfailure="alert('failed');" /></apex:page>
```

The result on the service console:
[image]

Do you have any clue how to set it right, so it won't ignore the newline elements?

Answer (score 2):

The Service Console is using a Rich Text editor, not an html editor. That means you'll need to use a text string that includes newline character codes where you want them. A `\n` is a newline character and a `\r` is a carriage return. I'd expect either one of those to do the job for you.

You may need to use `escapeUnicode()` on the text string to convert those to unicode characters for the editor.

Comment: This works only when I set the "emailbodyformat" property to "text" and that's a problem because the content contains images too. Have you managed to solve it in such a case too?

Comment: Didn't realize you were sending it with images. You could try using `escapeHTML4()` with your original syntax. `StripHTMLTags()` would remove all of the html tags without touching the newline characters. You may need to use some combination of these to achieve what you desire. See [string methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm%23apex_System_String_unescapeHtml4) for more.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these works. It looks like the control itself removes the new line characters or ignore it when I try to set default value, regardless any manipulation I do before setting it. I wonder if there any workaround or other way to get the same result.

Comment: I would suggest trying several different things. One is to try including the text as `PlainTextBody` with the unicode characters for the newlines or carriage returns. Try doing the same for the `HTMLbody` to see if either one works for you; especially since neither one is being `set`. I'd also try using `setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(treatAsTemplate)`. Finally, use `setCharset(characterSet)` and select a unicode set that includes the newlines and carriage returns you need. After that, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the Outgoing Email text as a Custom Field and merge to the emailbody parameter. Also, use 'innerHTML' as follows:

```
emailBody="{!case.HTMLbody}" id="RTF"/>
      <div style="display:none">
          <div id="html">
              <apex:outputText value="{!case.HTMLbody}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
          </div>
      </div>


       <script>
          CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
              evt.editor.setData(document.getElementById('html').innerHTML);
          })
      </script>
```

Hope this helps.